# Is there a way to suppress the Collectives annotations?

Tags: support, collectives

SO has just created an R collective. This means that posts that used to be tagged with "r" now show an "R" link before the tags that looks just like a big bright distracting tag, and users who have been "collectivized" have extra junk printed with their names.

Is there a way to suppress this? I'm not interested in the fact that someone has just joined a club.

Comment: Can you share an example of a question tagged with [tag:R] twice? I'm not seeing that. Are you referring to the collective link shown before the tags?

Comment: Use your favorite ad blocker to make the element disappear

Comment: @TylerH:  Yes, the collective link that is shown just before the tag.  But I already know that the tag r refers to the topic r, so it adds no new information for me.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine:  I don't use an ad blocker that could do that.  It seems surprising that StackOverflow (who must get income from ads) would want to encourage me to learn to use one.

Comment: I don't work for Stack, for the record. Neither do any of the other mods; we're volunteers. I also have no reason not to recommend using one (among other things, Stack regularly abuses banners, and uses several dark patterns in various popups, they use Google analytics and ads, and happily provide user data to Google without really caring. Privacy-centric alternatives to all these systems exist, and they've opted not to use them, but that's a whole other discussion). Also, Stack has a solid income from companies via, among other things, collectives, teams, that new jobs replacement thing, ...

Comment: "I do care about junk in the UI that distracts." - then you really want an ad blocker. SO constantly creates new UI junk. Not sure if they still do it, but one example is that they used to use announcement banners (AKA "look at me, this is very important") to announce new episodes of a (bad) podcast with no real significance to anyone. They'd trivially hit top 10 legitimate and high-profile sites (read: disregarding spam sites, and sites no one cares about) with the most annoying UI patterns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are not tags, but you can hide them with user styles or an adblocker browser add-on that includes an element-specific blocker. I use a user style with the following styles in Stylus:

```css
/* hides the collective content on the right sidebar */
#sidebar > div.s-sidebarwidget.js-join-leave-container {
    display: none;
}
#sidebar > .sidebar-subcommunity {
    display: none;
}

/* hides the "recommended by <collective>" verbiage */
.js-endorsements {
    display: none;
}

/* hides the trophy for Collectives ranking next to usernames in user cards*/
div.user-details > a[href^="/collectives"] {
    display: none;
}

ul.s-user-card--awards li a[href^="/collectives/"] {
    display: none;
}

/* hides collective buttons on the tag line */
a.subcommunity-topic-avatar {
    display: none;
}
div.js-community-icons {
    display: none;
}
```

applied to URLs on the `stackoverflow.com` domain.

There may be more specific/efficient CSS selectors available.

Comment: Thanks!  For me, the collective buttons entry also needs `!important` to take effect in Firefox.

Comment: @user2554330 Hmm, I am on Firefox as well and do not need !important declarations for these styles (though for many others on SO I do).

Comment: with the `!important`, I see it set to "inline-block" by matching class `s-avatar` from `stacks.css`.

Comment: Another one to suppress is `div.affiliate-badge`.